# Show thumbnails in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04

Following effect is observed:

- Browse files i.e. "Pictures" - no thumbnails
- Use attach file dialog - thumbnails are displayed
- Run Nautilus in sudo mode - thumbnails in "Pictures" are available.

How to fix that?

Comment: Have you confirmed ownership of the directory? There is also a setting that one can toggle to disable thumbnail caching, which is on a per-user basis. Have you toggled such a setting in the past?

Comment: Rerun ownership assignment is a good idea, though it does not explain why the attach file dialog does show thumbnails. What has been in the past, I can't tell for sure.