# Ubuntu 20.04: Desktop folders/files only become visible whenever a new one is created (after reboot)

Tags: 20.04, icons, launcher, .desktop

I had my Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop all cluttered with folders and files (yes, afterwards I've read that Linux does not like that), and suddenly the launchers were invisible.
*Edit: I'm talking about all graphic elements in the desktop workspace, all those of ~/desktop/**
I put the files themselves into other places and put a test file on the desktop.
After reboot, its icon was gone.
I decided to reset the desktop via terminal.
*Edit: dconf reset -f /org/gnome/*
Everything looked like a fresh install afterwards, but the behaviour is still off:
On boot, the desktop takes much longer to become functional, and no launchers are showing.
However, I can make them show up by creating a new folder or saving something to the desktop. Suddenly the "standard" desktop launchers and whatever I created after the reset are there.
Seems like something only loads when interacted with?

What can I do to get a normally working desktop again?
(Please do not suggest a new install :D )
I don't have Tweak tools and have not knowingly applied modifications to the desktop environment, even the wallpaper was the grey fossa.

I don't really use launchers/ edit: *desktop icons*; I only find it irritating that the desktop does not show, uhm, the desktop.
But I'm worried the dock being slow to start means there is a more serious problem.

Thank you for your help.

*Edit: Here are before - after pictures.
After system start, desktop is empty, no trashcan etc
took screenshot and chose "save to desktop" - result see second picture. All other icons appear. After next boot, all are "invisible" again.*

[image: Empty appearing Desktop after boot]
[image: icons appear after first screenshot saved to desktop]

Follow-up edit:

- made sure (I installed dconf editor) I have "show desktop icons" on
- found this; old, but someone has no picture thumbs until they interact with files:
  [Show thumbnails in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1322486/show-thumbnails-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Some kind of thumbnail database not being loaded in both cases?

Comment: "I decided to reset the desktop via terminal." How did you do that? Add the information to your question (use "edit"). What do you mean by "launchers"? The icons on the dock?